# Angular 9 Intercom API, how to fix CORS error?

Tags: angular, intercom

I'm trying to access intercom API and create a company there using their API
https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#create-or-update-company but getting CORS error!

```
URL = 'https://api.intercom.io/companies'

this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ....',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    })
 };

const path = this.URL + '/companies';
return this.http.post(path, data, {headers: this.httpOptions});
```

[image]

How to fix CORS error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intercome apis doest not work in the client side.
You need use server side package to make api call on intercome.

You can use one of them:

1- Nodejs http client package : `axios`

2- Official node package : `intercom-node`